# Repeated print in multiple threads implement by clone() API in Linux

Tags: linux, multithreading, printf, clone, semaphore

I attempt to use `clone()` API provided by Linux to write a function `mythread_create()`, just like `pthread_create()` defined in `pthread.h`. My code is as follows:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE
#include <sched.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

#define STACK_SIZE 1024*1024
#define FLAGS CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD

int thread_func(void *arg){
    printf("Thread %d, pid is %d\n", *((int *)arg), getpid());
    return 0;
}

pid_t mythread_create(int (*start_routine)(void *), void *arg){
    pid_t pid;

    void *stack = malloc(STACK_SIZE);
    if (!stack){
        perror("Error stack");
        return -1;
    }

    pid = clone(start_routine, stack + STACK_SIZE, FLAGS, arg);
    if (pid == -1){
        perror("Error clone");
        return -1;
    }
    return pid;
}

int mythread_join(pid_t pid){
    if (waitpid(pid, NULL, 0) == -1){
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}


int main(){
    pid_t pid1, pid2;
    int a = 1, b = 2;

    if (sem_init(&mutex_sem, 0, 1) != 0) {
        perror("Error sem");
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("Main thread, the pid is %d\n", getpid());

    pid1 = mythread_create(thread_func, &a);
    if (pid1 == -1){
        perror("Error mythread_create");
        exit(1);
    }

    pid2 = mythread_create(thread_func, &b);
    if (pid2 == -1){
        perror("Error mythread_create");
        exit(1);
    }

    mythread_join(pid1);
    mythread_join(pid2);

    printf("It's over\n");
    return 0;
}
```

When I compile and run it, I come across a problem. In the most cases, I can get correct answers, such as two situations, as follows:

```
Main thread, the pid is 20192
Thread 1, pid is 20193
Thread 2, pid is 20194
It's over
```

or

```
Main thread, the pid is 20311
Thread 2, pid is 20313
Thread 1, pid is 20312
It's over
```

But I occasionally encounter two types of error situations, as follows:

```
Main thread, the pid is 20427
Thread 1, pid is 20428
Thread 1, pid is 20428
Thread 2, pid is 20429
It's over
```

or

```
Main thread, the pid is 20668
Thread 2, pid is 20670
Thread 2, pid is 20670
Thread 1, pid is 20669
It's over
```

To solve this problem, I add the mutex semaphore around the `printf()` in the `thread_func()`. Then I can always get the expected outputs. But I attempt to using `pthread_create()` and `pthread_join()` implement by the pthread library to finish the same thing. I discover it can run correctly even though I can't add the mutex semaphore.

So I would like to figure out why it's like this? Thanks a lot for solving it!